# Levi-Civta symbol question

Tags: vector-analysis, tensors, kronecker-delta, kronecker-symbol

$$\delta_{kl}\epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon_{jki} = \delta_{kl} (\delta_{jl}\delta_{ki} - \delta_{ji}\delta_{kl})$$
$$\delta_{kl}\epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon_{jki} = \delta_{kj}\delta_{ki} -\delta_{ii}\delta_{ji} = \delta_{ji} - \delta{ji} = 0$$

What mistake I made here? Should I compute $\delta_{kl}\epsilon_{ijk} = \epsilon_{ijl}$ first because $k$ is not a free dummy index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your indexing seems wrong. In the first equation on the left you have three $k$-s, I guess one of them must be $l$.

Next, still first line, assuming the second $k$ is $l$:

$$
\epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon_{jli}=\epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon_{ijl}=\delta_{jj}\delta_{kl}-\delta_{jl}\delta_{kj}=3\delta_{kl}-\delta_{kl}=2\delta_{kl}
$$